# Ruby on Rails: Traverse Json Structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, directory, tree-traversal

```
def self.directory_hash(path, name=nil)
    data = {:parent => (name || path)}
    data[:children] = children = []
    Dir.foreach(path) do |entry|
      next if (entry == '..' || entry == '.')
      full_path = File.join(path, entry)
      if File.directory?(full_path)
        children << directory_hash(full_path, entry)
      else
      children << entry
      end
    end
    return data
  end
```

I used above method that returns the json given below:-

```
{:parent=>"public", :children=>["422.html", {:parent=>"applications", :children=>[{:parent=>"1", :children=>[{:parent=>"1", :children=>[{:parent=>"1", :children=>["configurations.xml"]}, {:parent=>"2", :children=>["configurations.xml"]}, "Projects.rar"]}, {:parent=>"2", :children=>[{:parent=>"9", :children=>["configurations.xml"]}, "rest.rar", {:parent=>"5", :children=>["configurations.xml"]}, {:parent=>"6", :children=>["configurations.xml"]}, {:parent=>"3", :children=>["configurations.xml"]}, {:parent=>"4", :children=>["configurations.xml"]}]}]}, {:parent=>"2", :children=>[{:parent=>"3", :children=>["Projects.rar"]}, {:parent=>"4", :children=>["rest.rar"]}]}]}, "500.html", "robots.txt", "favicon.ico", {:parent=>"data", :children=>[]}, "_index.html", "404.html"]}
```

Now in my view i want to show structure from above output so the view should look like

```
public
 422.html
 applications
  1
   1
    1
    2
  2
.....
.....
.....
```

An So On

I have a variable that keeps this json

```
@structure = ApplicationVersion.directory_hash("public")
```

So what code i will need to write to read the above json so that tree could be constructed?

Comment: its not json, its a hash.

Comment: Oh !!, Can you suggest how to create tree structure from this hash

Comment: it is already a tree structure, if you want to know how to display it, I would advice doing it in the browser with some javascript library, like http://www.jstree.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
your_hash = {:parent=>"public", :children=>["422.html", {:parent=>"applications", :children=>[{:parent=>"1", :children=>[{:parent=>"1", :children=>[{:parent=>"1", :children=>["configurations.xml"]}, {:parent=>"2", :children=>["configurations.xml"]}, "Projects.rar"]}, {:parent=>"2", :children=>[{:parent=>"9", :children=>["configurations.xml"]}, "rest.rar", {:parent=>"5", :children=>["configurations.xml"]}, {:parent=>"6", :children=>["configurations.xml"]}, {:parent=>"3", :children=>["configurations.xml"]}, {:parent=>"4", :children=>["configurations.xml"]}]}]}, {:parent=>"2", :children=>[{:parent=>"3", :children=>["Projects.rar"]}, {:parent=>"4", :children=>["rest.rar"]}]}]}, "500.html", "robots.txt", "favicon.ico", {:parent=>"data", :children=>[]}, "_index.html", "404.html"]}
```

```
new_hash= your_hash.to_s.gsub(/(\[\"\S*\"\])/,'').gsub(/(\[|\]|\{|\})/,'').gsub('=>',',').gsub(',,',',')

new_hash.split(',').each {|i| puts i if i.strip[0] != ":"}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It has worked for me. Just another thing i want to know if this is possible to create <ul> and <li> tags for that output produced by above code so that i could use JsTree plugin?

Comment: I want to create the above output in the following format:- <div id="demo1" class="demo" style="height:100px;">
 <ul>
  <li id="phtml_1"><a href="#">Root node 1</a>
   <ul>
    <li id="phtml_11"><a href="#">Child node 1</a>
     <ul>
      <li id="phtml_111"><a href="#">Child node 11</a></li>
      <li id="phtml_222"><a href="#">Child node 22</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="phtml_21"><a href="#">Child node 2</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>